# How to make a button in Unity?

Tags: button, input, touch, unity-game-engine

How can I make a button for mobile devices? I have a pause screen and a script that accepts touch but it activates when I click on any part of the screen, not just the button.

How can I fix it to activate only on the button? My script is attached to cube with invisible material so basically I want to activate script only when player presses the area around cube.

I wasn't sure how to paste code here so I used pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/ERC39TuU

Comment: Post code for better solution.

Answer (score 1):

See [GUI.Button reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html).

```
function OnGUI() {
    if (GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,100,50), "Click"))
        Debug.Log("Clicked button!");
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you but I have my own custom button and I want to load something when I click on my button.

Comment: I'm assuming by your "custom button" you mean an image. If that's the case, just replace `"Click"` with a reference to that Texture2D.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of unity they implemented a much better GUI designer. I would look into using Canvas. Adding images to your buttons and functions is much easier the nusing OnGUI in my opinion.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-canvas